# Bash: menu-complete only for few matches

Tags: bash, command-line-interface

With Bash auto-completion, is there a way to cycle through matches using menu-complete only if there are 1-2 options, and use listing with complete otherwise?

**Example**

home directory contains Desktop, Documents, Downloads, Projects and Public

```
~$ cd D<tab><tab> # lists matches
Desktop    Documents    Downloads
~$ cd De<tab> # completes Desktop

~$ cd P<tab> # completes Projects
~$ cd Projects<tab> # completes Public
```

The former is `complete` behavior, the latter is `menu-complete`.
I want it to choose the second option if there are only 1-2 matches, the first if there are 3 or more.

Comment: This look like one of my question, seems impossible : http://serverfault.com/questions/41638/bash-completion-dynamic-behavior

Comment: Indeed, it's similar to your question - though not quite the same.

Either way, it should be possible by modifying the original completion script - but looking at /etc/bash_completion, I don't see any obvious hooks...

Answer (score 2):

It seems like there is no way.

I know you specifically asked for bash, but in case you want to give zsh a try, it uses ordinary list completion on the first press of tab, and cycles through the possible values on the second press. I think that is very convenient, and switching is a no-brainer as zsh is very similar to bash.

Comment: Yeah, I haven't made any progress either. There probably is a way, but it would require more familiarity with Bash's interals.

As for zsh, ... well, I have no experience with it so far, and switching just for this one feature seems odd - but I might give it a try in a virtual machine. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hit tab twice? Or are you trying to get something like a command then either arg1 or arg2 listed after the command?

**ANSWER**:

You'll want to edit your **/etc/inputrc** and add the following line somewhere:

```
"\C-i": menu-complete
```

Then run this command to immediately set your changes:

**#: bind -f /etc/inputrc**

Unfortunately, I don't see a way to limit it by the number of choices, but that is how you can switch it alternate as you hit the 'tab' key

Reference:[independentchaos.com](http://independentchaos.com/index.php/2009/08/bash_completion-tips/)

Comment: When I hit tab twice, I get a choice of options - e.g. D<tab> lists Documents and Downloads. If there are only two options, I want the options to be cycled instead of listed.

Comment: I think I found your answer.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm afraid I already knew about menu-complete. I've clarified my original post with an example, hopefully that will help.